# Error when inserting image into Postgresql using pgAdmin 4 sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, image, pgadmin-4

I have a Postgresql table to store image filenames and images:

```
create table images (imagenme text, img bytea);
```

I am trying to insert an image using pgAdmin 4 SQL Tool:

```
insert into images(img) values (bytea('C:\Users\username\Desktop\image_files\img1_1_1.jpg'));
```

When I run this in SQL Tool, I get this error:

```
ERROR: invalid input sytax for type bytea
LINE 1: insert into images(img) values (bytea('C:\Users\username\Desktop...
                                              ^
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 39
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a link to the part of the documentation that makes you believe there's a `bytea()` *function* that takes a path to a file?

Comment: @stickybit I can not, I am new to Postgres. Can it be done in SQL, or do I need a Python script?

Comment: Have you had a look at [this part of the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html)? You need to get the file's content in of the encodings listed there and use that as your value.

Comment: Or have a look at the duplicates, if some of the methods presented there work for you.